# can I call ASP.NET web API in React Native?

Tags: asp.net, react-native, asp.net-web-api

I am new to react native. I want to know how to call ASP.NET api from react native. I don't have any URL to call inside fetch(). Can any one point me in right direction? It is fair to say I don't know much about ASP.NET web API.

Comment: I'm not a react guy, but you call an ASP.NET api the same way you call any API. There's nothing special about an end point written in ASP.NET. Is the problem calling the end point, or do you need to know how to call an API in general? Or do you just not know the url of the end point?

Comment: In API document this is written:  **DELETE /api/2.0/B2C/DeleteRecord**
 to Delete a custom object record And i don't know how to use this in my project.

Comment: You need to send a DELETE request to the server with that end point. Such as `http://aserver.com/api2.0/B2C/DeleteRecord` You probably need to include a record identifier somehow as well, usually as part of the URL but the documentation should spell that out to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is good library available in React-native to handle api calls **axios**.

**Installation**

`npm install axios` for npm

`yarn add axios` for yarn users

**Delete Request**

```
axios.delete(URL).then((response)=>{
   console.log(response);
   //Do whatever you want to do with data
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
})
```

For more info read here(Its pretty good library to handle Api calls)

[Axios Docs Github](https://github.com/qiangmao/axios#readme)